# Normal-inverse-Wishart distribution

Tags: bayesian, prior, wishart-distribution

The Normal-inverse-Wishart distribution is a conjugate prior for the multivariate normal distribution when the mean and covariance are unknown.   I understand that conjugate priors are mathematically convenient but are there specific applications where the justification for using the Normal-inverse-Wishart distribution prior goes beyond convenience?

Comment: I would suggest  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155059/justification-for-conjugate-prior for consideration

Answer (score 2):

One application is the Gibbs Sampling from a Dirichlet Process mixture model, where a conjugate prior is required. See page 33 of the pdf below

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kbe/dp_tutorial.pdf

Comment: Hi @George, welcome to XV. OP seems to be asking about when conjugacy's justification goes *beyond* its being required or convenience.