# Why do we look to have a conjugate prior in Bayesian learning?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, conjugate-prior

I am looking into Bayesian learning for the first time ever and am just wondering why we look to have a conjugate prior to carry out our estimation with.

Comment: you don't have to, its for computational ease.

Comment: This question may be useful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155059/justification-for-conjugate-prior

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to have a conjugate prior and indeed, you should not have a conjugate prior unless it fits your prior knowledge.  Many conjugate prior distributions are good approximations of actual knowledge. Some can be problematic, like the inverse Wishart, when used in a way that is not representative of information or as a diffuse prior.

Conjugate priors permit fast Bayesian updating, which can be valuable in high dimension problems.

Conjugacy only exists for a fraction of likelihood functions.  You cannot always use one.