# Converting Prior Knowledge into a Bayesian Prior

Tags: bayesian

Suppose I flip a coin 10 times and get 7 heads - based on a Binomial Distribution, I can create a Likelihood Function and estimate the probability of getting a head is 0.7.

Now, suppose someone tells me that they have very strong evidence to believe that the probability of getting a head is 0.9. Suppose I decide to use a Beta Distribution(alpha, beta) as a prior.

**My Question:** I know that the Expected Value of the Beta Distribution is 'alpha/(alpha + beta)'. If I want to use the Prior Information that was provided to me - does this mean that I have choose values of 'alpha and beta' such that 'alpha/(alpha+beta)' = 0.9? For example - based on the n = 10 samples I observed, in this case, would alpha = 9 and beta = 1?

Comment: That would only fix the prior mean. The "problem" is that you get the same prior mean for, say, alpha=90 and beta=10. The latter however entails much stronger beliefs (lower prior variance). This is maybe helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155059/justification-for-conjugate-prior/155116#155116

Comment: Take a look again at this answer: [Help me understand Bayesian prior and posterior distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/58792/237901), which visualizes the process quite nicely and was suggested to you in your previous question about Bayesian inference for a proportion.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, **your problem is not defined correctly**:

- The likelihood is a Binomial distribution (you flip the coin)
- The Prior is a Beta distribution (representing the distribution of
  the parameter p of the Binomial)
- Beta is a conjugate prior for Binomial, it means the posterior is still a Beta distribution.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) you can find the following details:
[image]

Therefore, in order to identify the "believe", that is a Beta distributions, you need 2 parameters:

- alpha & beta (your problem is solved)

OR

- mean & variance, in order to solve this equation:

$$\mathbf E[X]=\frac\alpha{\alpha+\beta}$$

$$\mathbf V[X]= \frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta) ^2(\alpha+\beta+1) }$$

as reported here: [Calculating the parameters of a Beta distribution using the mean and variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12232/calculating-the-parameters-of-a-beta-distribution-using-the-mean-and-variance).

**Therefore: Variance is missing.**

Comment: ... and OP only specified a single moment, the mean. Welcome to CrossValidated!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. This is a MathJax enabled site: [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1604/237901). Please use LaTex to type equations as it makes for more readable answers.

Answer (score 6):

> does this mean that I have choose values of 'alpha and beta' such that 'alpha/(alpha+beta)' = 0.9?

That's correct, but the actual values you choose determine how strong your prior is.

In this particular setup, there's an intuitive explanation of the Beta prior: it is equivalent to having previously observed $\alpha$ heads and $\beta$ tails from the same coin.

You can thus see that $(\alpha, \beta)=(9,1)$ is much weaker than $(\alpha, \beta)=(900000,100000)$.

Answer (score 3):

The typical approach in this case would be to use the conjugate prior (the beta distribution) for the unknown probability parameter and parameterise this using a stipulated **prior mean** $0 \leqslant \mu_0 \leqslant 1$ and **prior effective-sample-size** $n_0 \geqslant 0$.  You can then use the reparameterisation of the beta distribution with parameters:

$$\begin{align}
\alpha &= \mu_0 (n_0+2), \\[6pt]
\beta &= (1-\mu_0) (n_0+2). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

From the information you have given you would choose $\mu_0 = 0.9$ and you would then have to choose an appropriate value for the prior effective sample-size.  This is a measure of the strength of your prior belief --- the higher the effective-sample-size the stronger your prior belief (and so the lower the prior variance).  You describe the prior belief as "very strong" so you could choose a value like $n_0 = 100$ to represent this, which would mean that you consider your prior belief to be as strong as if it were formed from one-hundred observed data points.